# General solution to a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Consider the equation $u_{xx}+2u_{xy}+u_{yy}=0.$ Write the equation in the coordinates $s=x$ and $t=x-y$ and find the general solution of the equation.

We have that $x=s$ and $y=s-t,$ thus $u(x,y)=u(s,s-t)=v(s,t)$. Now I know I must compute partial derivatives of $x$ and $y$ by using the chain rule to find a general solution, but I am not sure how to apply it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$s=x$ and $t=x-y$  hense   $s_x=1$ ; $s_y=0$ ; $t_x=1$ ; $t_y=-1$

$$u_x=v_s s_x+v_t t_x=v_s+v_t$$
$$u_{xx}=(v_{ss} s_x+v_{st} t_x)+(v_{ts} s_x+v_{tt} t_x)=v_{ss}+v_{st}+v_{ts}+v_{tt}=v_{ss}+2v_{st}+v_{tt}$$
$$u_{xy}=(v_{ss} s_y+v_{st} t_y)+(v_{ts} s_y+v_{tt} t_y)=-v_{st}-v_{tt}$$
$$u_y=v_s s_y+v_t t_y=-v_t$$
$$u_{yy}=-v_{ts} s_y-v_{tt} t_y=v_{tt}$$

$$u_{xx}+2u_{xy}+u_{yy}=v_{ss}+2v_{st}+v_{tt}+2(-v_{st}-v_{tt})+v_{tt}=v_{ss}$$
$$v_{ss}=0$$

There is no difficulty to continue...